# Log message referring to Gatekeeper appears occasionally when running simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, osx-mountain-lion

I am developing an app for iPhone. Sometimes I get this log :

> Named service 'com.apple.PersistentURLTranslator.Gatekeeper' not found. assetsd is down or misconfigured. Things will not work the way you expect them to.
>   Tue Oct  4 11:59:21 my-Mac-Pro.local[2958] : Named service 'com.apple.assetsd.changehub' not found. assetsd is down or misconfigured. Things will not work the way you expect them to.

It is happening when I present a modal `UIImagePickerController`, but not every time.

Has anybody got any ideas?

Comment: Are you running a beta version of mountain lion?

Comment: I just now upgraded to Mountain Lion and I'm getting this too, from an Xcode project which worked in Lion.

Comment: i've got the same... how fix it?

Comment: Have you also upgraded to Xcode 4.4?

Comment: I also got the same problem when I run my iPhone app on the iPad simulator. And the image I selected cannot be picked successfully. If I switch the simulator to iPhone resolution, such problem won't occur and the image can be successfully selected. Is this the same at your side?

Answer (score 7):

I agree with the other respondents that this is a bug.

In the mean time, a work-around is to quit the iOS Simulator and restart it.  I've had to do this as I alternate testing between different devices.

Comment: Seems that the iOS Simulator was getting confused when switching from iPhone to iPad. Thanks, quitting the simulator helped...I did lost 20 mins trying to figure out something in my code. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the beta of Xcode 4.5 to see if this behavior exists ... If it does, I suggest filing Radars : https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

The new os mountain lion has a feature called Gatekeeper that the service is trying to run through.  What i have heard is that there are lots of bugs with Xcode and the new OS.  My guess is that it is a bug and will probably be resolved once apple comes out with an update and many bug fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Agree this is a bug. Relaunching simulator didn't work for me, but after I manually ran the app in question in simulator (as opposed to launching via 'Run' in Xcode) I was fine, and was subsequently able to use Run as normal.