# UIImagePickerController crashes on iPad simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to display a UiImagePicker in a popover, as it is supposed to be done for iPad. But when a picture is selected and *imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:* is triggered, I get the following log:

**Named service 'com.apple.PersistentURLTranslator.Gatekeeper' not found. assetsd is down or misconfigured. Things will not work the way you expect them to.**

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

   imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
   imagePickerController.delegate = self;
   imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   // Check device
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
       [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }
   else {
       [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   }

   // More code here to save the selected image
}

- (IBAction)showImagePicker:(id)sender
{
   if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
       [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
   }
   else {
       popoverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc]
                          initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
       [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).frame
                                          inView:self.view
                        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                        animated:YES];
}
```

What could I be missing or doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645553/log-message-referring-to-gatekeeper-appears-occasionally-when-running-simulator) in Xcode for ML. Try to quit the simulator and restart and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be something like that... I get such log message on iPad simulator if I first run the app on iPhone simulator after having opened the project, and viceversa. I tried running on real device and it works.